# using API key on client side - flask python

Tags: python, api, flask

I am trying to find a way to secure my API that is using flask.

I don't have any webpages.
I don't have any "routes" I only have "Resources".
I don't have a username and password and don't need a database.

I only need to find a way to use the API Key on the client side for authentication.
I already have an api key that I generated, and I put this as a variable on the server but I don't have ANY examples on how to add this to the client app.

Serverside

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, request, Response
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import intermedia_choose_action_flask 
import subprocess
from io import StringIO 
import sys
import sqlite_companysearch
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
SECRET_KEY = "a long set of strings I got from running a command in linux terminal"

app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY

class addspamblacklistspecific(Resource):
    def get(self, emailordomain):
        count = 0
        sqlite_companysearch.comp_searchall_intermedia()
        selection_cid = sqlite_companysearch.comp_searchall_intermedia.cid_selection_results            
        for cid in selection_cid:
            
            subprocess.Popen(["python3", "/home/tech/scripts/Intermedia_automate/intermedia_choose_action.py", "--addblockspecific", "--cp", cid, "--ed", emailordomain], bufsize=10, errors='replace')
            count = count + 1 
            if count == 3:
                time.sleep(60)
                count = 0

        return "command completed succesfully"

        

api.add_resource(addspamblacklistspecific, "/addspamblacklistspecific/<string:emailordomain>")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the client side:

```
from flask import json
import requests

#where do I put in a secret key?

def email_or_domain_selection():
    email_or_domain_selection.email_select = input("""Enter an email or domain.
(NOTE: domains must have a "*" symbol infront of the name. For example *company.com)

Enter Email or Domain :""")
    eselect = email_or_domain_selection.email_select
    return email_or_domain_selection.email_select
email_or_domain_selection()

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.get(BASE + "addspamblacklistspecific/"+email_or_domain_selection.email_select)
print(response.text)
```

How do I add the api key to the client side?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the key available to the client, or how the client should pass the key to the server to authenticate requests?

Comment: More so, how can I pass the key to the server to authenicate the requests? I have seen a bunch of examples of how to add the key to the serverside but not how to add it to the request. I am currently researching myself and I think I found a method using basic authenication. Not my favorite but I will take ANYTHING that works. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAgll-Z5mc8

Comment: Something like [this](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) might be what you want?  There are doubtless other libs out there - searching for something like 'flask authentication (or authorization) headers' might find them.